# Operating a solar panel at lower than MPP

Tags: solar-charge-controller

The power curve for a solar panel drops off slowly to the left of MPP (lower voltage) and more rapidly to the right of MPP (higher voltage).

Observing my MPPT CC,  when it needs to "throttle" the power from the panels it always operates on the steep or high voltage side of the power curve.

Is that how the MPPT CC is designed to operate?

Comment: It depends on the design

Comment: Makes sense to me that it would try to operate on that side all the time. For one thing, it matches our usual interpretation of circuit behaviour. For another thing, drawing excessive current would dissipate more power in the wiring and the MPPT converter. It's basically asking why we leave solar panels disconnected instead of short-circuited a solar panel to turn them off.

Comment: Great user253751,  that makes sense.  Thanks for answering the question.

Answer (score 1):

There are many different algorithms for tracking MPPT.

“ Different MPPT techniques have been proposed in the [literature](https://www.hindawi.com/journals/ijp/2016/1728398/) such as;

- [(1] the perturbation and observation (P&O) technique
- [2] the incremental conductance (IncCond) technique
- [3] ripple correlation technique
- [4] short circuit current (SCC) technique
- [5] open circuit voltage (OCV) technique

Using Voc/Isc = R.mpt can be done with pulses.

Differentiating computed power or V and I leads to the Inc.Cond method to hunt for **maximum conductance or minimum Rmpt.**

Ripple tracking has speed and efficiency advantages with added complexity as the lowest source equivalent Rpv also minimizes ripple.

All these techniques must track changes due to temperature, solarity, load and complex impedances to minimize errors in tracking.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.

Answer (score 0):

Operating on the low voltage side would be called "shunt regulation" and involve burning wasted current in some load (resistor).

This IS a thing; the resistor is called a "load dump" and sometimes used to heat water. More common with off grid wind turbines than solar; it helps reduce the speed of the turbine (though furling systems or blade feathering are also needed to prevent overspeed in windy weather)

However I have heard of its use in satellites where air cooling the solar cells is impossible, and removing the wasted energy from the cells helps keep their temperature down. Ideally the load dump can be used to control the temperature of the cold side of the satellite.